# Marginal vs. conditional models of vector autoregression (VAR)

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, marginal-distribution

I have a vector autoregression, VAR(1). All random variables are weakly stationary and our white noises are all iid:

$$\begin{pmatrix}X_{1,t}\\X_{2,t}\\\vdots\\X_{k,t}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{11}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{1,k}X_{k,t-1}\\\alpha_{21}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{2,k}X_{k,t-1}\\\vdots\\\alpha_{k,1}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{k,k}X_{k,t-1}\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}\varepsilon_{1,t}\\\varepsilon_{2,t}\\\vdots\\\varepsilon_{k,t}\end{pmatrix}$$

It follows that

$$X_{1,t}=\alpha_{11}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{1,k}X_{k,t-1}+\varepsilon_{1,t}$$
$$X_{2,t}=\alpha_{21}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{2,k}X_{k,t-1}+\varepsilon_{2,t}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$X_{k,t}=\alpha_{k1}X_{1,t-1}+...+\alpha_{kk}X_{k,t-1}+\varepsilon_{k,t}$$

Questions:

1. I am wondering if my equations represent the **marginal** models of each of my random variables? I was thinking the equations represent **conditional** models.
2. If indeed they are conditional models, how could I go about obtaining marginal models?

Comment: Could you make what you are asking more specific? What exactly do you mean by marginal/conditional models?

Comment: It had just been ages since I'd been on. Sorry, Richard!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One particular equation of a VAR model targets the **conditional** mean (and the conditional distribution, if you are taking on distributional assumptions on model errors) of a univariate time series $X_{i,t}$ for $i \in 1,\dotsc,k$ and the conditioning is on past values of all the $k$ time series.

In the context of the $k$-variate random process, this is also a **marginal** model because it targets only one time series out of $k$.

So it is both a conditional and a marginal model - from certain perspectives.

(You could always pick some other variable or a different lag that is not in the model, then with respect to that particular variable/lag the model would not be conditional.)

Comment: I don't really think that captures the idea of marginal. Suppose you have two random variables X and Y. Their joint density is p(X, Y). The conditional density of X given Y is p(X|Y). This "targets" only one of the two RVs using your train of thought, but obviously it is the conditional density.

Comment: It could just be that terms are used a little loosely here, I don't think it is obvious from the question what exactly is meant here

Comment: @hejseb, it could be. I just posted my two pence the way I understood the question.

Comment: Thank you for you response. Time series is a wild subject--it's interesting to think that we could have both conditional and marginal at the same time! 

I realized if I just abuse the back shift operator I can get my marginal models.

Answer (score 0):

like any of these problems you need to first calculate the moving average representation; this will give you the steady state joint distribution, then you integrate out  k-1 variables to get the marginal distribution,however, if the errors are multivariate normal(MVN) then the joint will be MVN(some regularity conditions apply) and hence you only need to know the mean and variance to specify the marginal distribution these also come off the MA representation